# как растянуть матрицу в numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

Как растянуть матрицу в numpy

к примеру

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3]]
```

превратить в

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 3, 3],
 [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: А где ваши собственные попытки решить задачу и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]] )

# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])
```

```
np.pad(a, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode="symmetric")

# array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 3, 3],
#        [2, 2, 3, 3]])
```